# How to append new lines of text to the end after cat'ing multiple line file into variable

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, sh

I have a file with contents like this:

```
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee fff
```

If I cat the file into a variable:

```
var=`cat file.txt`
```

I can echo the contents like this:

```
echo $var
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff
```

Or like this, with the newlines preserved:

```
echo "$var"
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee fff
```

I want to add new lines of text to the variable $var, so that when I write $var back out to a file:

```
echo "$var" > newfile.txt
```

The contents of newfile.txt will have my new lines at the end:

```
var2=`cat newfile.txt`
echo "$var2"
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee fff
ggg hhh
iii jjj
```

I cannot figure out how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: What if you just do `var=$var$(cat newfile)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ var2=$(< file.txt)
$ var2+=$'ggg hhh\niii jjj\n'
$ echo "$var2" > newfile.txt
$ cat new file.txt
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee fff
ggg hhh
iii jjj
```

The `+=` operator can be used to append values to the end of an existing parameter. You could also forgo modifying the value of `var2`, and simply write your additional data like this:

```
$ var2=$(< file.txt)
$ { echo "$var2"
>   printf "%s\n" "ggg hhh" "iii jjj"
> } > newfile.txt
```

---

Some updates to avoid `bash` extensions.

1. `$(< file.txt)` is a more-efficient implementation of the standard `$(cat file.txt)`.
2. `$'...'` is not supported by `dash`, but embedded newlines should still work:

   ```
   var2="$string1
   $string2"
   ```
3. `printf "%s\n" "$string1" "$string2"` should work fine in `dash`.

Comment: I had to make a slight change. The contents I want to add were not really fixed strings like 'iii jjj', but variables. So I had to do this:
var2+=$'\n'"${string1} ${string2}"
The variables needed to be in "" while the \n needed to be in ''.

Comment: I have found that this works in /bin/bash but not in /bin/sh (which I think is dash on my OS)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than making the assignment and then appending data to the variable, just do what you want when you make the initial assignment:

```
var=$( cat file.txt; echo ggg hhh; echo iii jjj; )
```

or

```
var=$( cat file.txt - << EOF
ggg hhh
iii jjj
EOF
)
```

Comment: In my case it's not possible to do it all in the initial assignment. I need to read in a large file, go through a lot of logic where I periodically append to the variable, and at the end (if there was a change) write out the new file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ var="$var
> xxx yyy
> zzz ggg"

$ echo $var
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
eee fff
xxx yyy
zzz ggg
```

Comment: I found this works after posting my question, but it's somewhat unwieldy to write into a shell script. I think it's sensitive to whitespace, i.e. I can't have lines 2 & 3 indented.

Answer (score -1):

You just echo it in append mode

```
echo "$var" >> newfile.txt
```

the >> means it won't open the file in plain write mode. It opens in O_RDRW | O_APPEND

Comment: I want to avoid multiple file writes.